# How to make a custom sum in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a running sum on a Dataframe that follows some conditions, sum all previous values with same 'first index current day' value and condiction is true, the pseudocode would be something like

```
df_ = df[first index current day:current index] #Delimiter dataframe range from begin of day until current row
df_ = df_[df_['toSum'] == True] #drop False
result = sum(df_['sales']) #Sum all sales until now with 'toSum' == True
```

This is very easy using a loop or even a apply but take too much time, my dataframe have more than 1000k rows, the best I could do until now is use threads but if it's possible to vectorize that algorithm it would be a lot fastter

The result is something like this:

| Actual Id | First ID Actual Day | Sales | toSum | AcumulativeDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | True | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | True | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | False | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | False | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | True | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | True | 1 |
| 6 | 5 | 1 | True | 2 |
| 7 | 5 | 1 | False | 2 |
| 8 | 5 | 1 | False | 2 |
| 9 | 5 | 1 | True | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) over `First ID Actual Day` to get all previous values with same first day ID. Then, multiply the boolean column `toSum` with `Sales` so that `cumsum` can interpret the `False` values as zeros. Remove the indices with [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) and make the attribution to the variable.

```py
import pandas as pd

d= {'Actual Id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9},
 'First ID Actual Day': {0: 0,1: 0,2: 0,3: 0,4: 0,5: 5,6: 5,7: 5,8: 5,9: 5},
 'Sales': {0: 1.0,1: 11.33,2: 1.0,3: 31.2,4: 1.0,5: 241.14,6: 1.0,7: 1.0,8: 1.0,9: 54.22},
 'toSum': {0: True,1: True,2: False,3: False,4: True,5: True,6: True,7: False,8: False,9: True}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['AcumulativeDay'] = df.groupby(['First ID Actual Day'])\
                        .apply(lambda x: (x['Sales']*x['toSum'])\
                        .cumsum()).droplevel(0)
```

```py
   Actual Id  First ID Actual Day   Sales  toSum  AcumulativeDay
0          0                    0    1.00   True            1.00
1          1                    0   11.33   True           12.33
2          2                    0    1.00  False           12.33
3          3                    0   31.20  False           12.33
4          4                    0    1.00   True           13.33
5          5                    5  241.14   True          241.14
6          6                    5    1.00   True          242.14
7          7                    5    1.00  False          242.14
8          8                    5    1.00  False          242.14
9          9                    5   54.22   True          296.36
```

Answer (score 0):

After having the table filtered as you did use:

```
df['cumsum'] = df['sales'].cumsum()
```

You may want to have the dataframe sorted by date.

Comment: But how could I apply filers in a cumsum and concatenate all days?